# how to make a function for validating TextInputLayout kotlin

Tags: android-studio, validation, kotlin, android-textinputlayout

I want to make a function for validation of text inputs(material design) and use it multiple times 
I have a working code but I know it is dirty 
how to optimize it?
this is my onClick method

```
 fun addItems(view: View) {

        val name1 = etName.text.toString().trim()
        val quantity1 = etQuantity.text.toString()
        val gst1 = etGst.text.toString()
        val amount1 = etAmount.text.toString()
        fun showToast() {
            runOnUiThread(kotlinx.coroutines.Runnable {
                Toast.makeText(this, "$name1 Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }) // runnable is used because activity is immediately killed and toast cannot be sowed hence it is to be done on ui tread
            finish()
        }

        if (name1.isNotBlank() && quantity1.isNotBlank() && amount1.isNotBlank()) {

            if (quantity1.toInt() != 0) {
                if (amount1.toInt() != 0) {
                    Thread {
                        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDb::class.java, "BookDB")
                            .build()
                        val item = ItemEntity()
                        item.itemName = name1
                        item.quantity = quantity1
                        item.amount = amount1
                        if (boolProcessWithGST) {
                            if (gst1.isNotBlank()) {
                                if (gst1.toInt() != 0) {
                                    // process with GST
                                    item.gst = gst1
                                    db.abstractItemDao().saveItems(item)
                                    showToast()

                                } else runOnUiThread {
                                    tilGST.error = "Tax can't be 0%"
                                    etGst.requestFocus()
                                } // ui operation only works on main/ui thread
                            } else runOnUiThread {
                                tilGST.error = "Disable toggle if no TAX"
                                etGst.requestFocus()
                            }
                        } else {
                            // process without gst
                            db.abstractItemDao().saveItems(item)
                            showToast()
                        }
                    }.start()
                } else {
                    tilAmount.error = "Amount can't be 0"
                    etAmount.requestFocus()
                }
            } else {
                tilQuantity.error = "Quantity can't be 0"
                etQuantity.requestFocus()
            }
        } else Toast.makeText(this, "please fill the required fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

I want to use the same validation for another onClick in the same activity

I tried making a function but the android studio suggests -> Cascade if should be replaced with when. how to do so?
function I made

```
private fun isValidInput(): Boolean {
        var isValid = true
        val name1 = etName.text.toString().trim()
        val quantity1 = etQuantity.text.toString()
        val gst1 = etGst.text.toString()
        val amount1 = etAmount.text.toString()

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root_layout)
        if (name1.isEmpty()) {
            tilName.isErrorEnabled = true
            tilName.error = "Required"
            isValid = false
        } else tilName.isErrorEnabled = false


        if (quantity1.isEmpty()) {
            tilQuantity.isErrorEnabled = true
            tilQuantity.error = "Required"
            isValid = false
        } else if (quantity1.toInt() == 0) {
            tilQuantity.isErrorEnabled = true
            tilQuantity.error = "can't be 0"
        } else tilQuantity.isErrorEnabled = false


        if (amount1.isEmpty()) {
            tilAmount.isErrorEnabled = true
            tilAmount.error = "Required"
            isValid = false
        }else if (amount1.toInt() == 0) {
            tilAmount.isErrorEnabled = true
            tilAmount.error = "can't be 0"
        } else tilAmount.isErrorEnabled = false


        if (gst1.isEmpty()) {
            tilGST.isErrorEnabled = true
            tilGST.error = "Required"
            isValid = false
        }else if (gst1.toInt() == 0) {
            tilGST.isErrorEnabled = true
            tilGST.error = "can't be 0"
        } else tilGST.isErrorEnabled = false

        return isValid
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I recommend using **MVVM** or any other architectural pattern(MVC, MVP, MVI ... ) to clean your code and achieve separation of concerns principle. in short, you should have a separate class for your application logic(in MVVM its called **ViewModel**) and **repository** class for accessing and saving your data like database or API call, and your activity is only responsible for the **views**. this will make your code much cleaner.
for starter, you can use this guide : [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide)
but there are tons of other resources out there which you can learn from

for your warning "Cascade if should be replaced with when" you can just hit Alt+enter and let the android studio do it for you. if it's not working you can do it yourself. it means something like this

**with if:**

```
if (num == 0) {
        //do something
    } else if (num < 5) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
```

**convert to when looks like this:**

```
 when {
        num == 0 -> {
            //do something
        }
        num < 5 -> {
            //do something
        }
        else -> {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

`when` is called `switch/case` in other programming languages.